# What sets have been named in a punny way?

Tags: sets

I heard speculation that [set 40358 "Bean There, Donut That"](https://brickset.com/sets/40358-1/Bean-There-Donut-That) is the only set that LEGO ever produced where the name of the set is also a joke.  Is that true?
Or are there other sets names that contain a pun or double meaning?

Comment: It would make sense that there wouldn't be very many sets with punny names. Jokes tend to be regional and thus difficult to translate or localize.

Comment: I can understand their motivation for avoiding it, but I am always amazed at how our regulars can find things with very little to go on.  I thought that it would be more likely in the promotional sets since those tend to be locally-focused, but flipping through brickset I didn't see anything.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: I don't think that's much of a problem, given that localized set names are sometimes not even remotely related in meaning. Having a pun in one language that is entirely absent in another one would thus not pose any issue.

Comment: OP, please clarify: Are you looking specifically for *puns*, or for any kinds of jokes (for instance, I'd count the Ninjago *Template of the Ultimate Ultimate Weapon* to be quite joke-like, even though it's not a pun)?

Comment: I thought this was going to be harder to find examples of so I aimed the question pretty broadly, but since we've got good answers for the narrower version we should probably stick with puns instead of jokes generally.

Comment: Not a pun, but still an "insider joke" - the [Saturn V rocket set](https://brickset.com/article/28363/secrets-of-the-saturn-v)  has a piece count of 1969 which reflects the year of the Apollo 11 moon landing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A spoof on Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom:

## [1355-1: Temple of Gloom](https://brickset.com/sets/1355-1/Temple-of-Gloom)

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Not a great pun, but the 2016 advent calendar was:

## [40222-1: Christmas Build-Up](https://brickset.com/sets/40222-1/Christmas-Build-Up)

[image]

Sort-of a pun/double-meaning on LEGO being a building toy, and the set being meant to build-up to Christmas.

[The 2017 version also has the same name](https://brickset.com/sets/40253-1/Christmas-Build-Up).

Comment: They did this in 2017 too with the same name.  https://brickset.com/sets/40253-1/Christmas-Build-Up  But so far those are the only two "build-up"s they've done.

Answer (score 18):

## [3852-1: Sunblock](https://brickset.com/sets/3852-1/Sunblock) (or Sun *Block* as styled on the packaging)

[image]

Here "Block" takes on 3 meaning, as part of the word "Sunblock", a pun on LEGO blocks (though I prefer to call them bricks), and a reference to the game play where you try to block your opponents from making another move.

Answer (score 13):

This set name is almost-certainly intended as a humorous reference to [Knight Rider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_Rider):

## [30376-1: Knighton Rider](https://brickset.com/sets/30376-1/Knighton-Rider)

[image]

Comment: Hmm, but Knight Rider was about Hoff and his *car* KITT, rather than a bike ;)

Comment: Also, it would be better to combine your answer into a single definitive answer, rather than lots of separate ones, otherwise Chicks won't be able to accept any of them ;)

Comment: I think you meant "humorous", instead of [humerus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humerus) ;)

Answer (score 11):

Bad but probably intentional pun, this set has *dual* bikes that *duel*:

## [8305-1: Duel Bikes](https://brickset.com/sets/8305-1/Duel-Bikes)

[image]

Likewise, there is [4587-1: Duel Racers](https://brickset.com/sets/4587-1/Duel-Racers).

Answer (score 3):

42072 Whack! and 42073 Bash! are not punny but cannot be taken serously either. In Germany, they are called Zack! and Bumms! 
[image]
[image]